# iOS-Creating a directory in Documents

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create a folder in my documents directory and I want to be able to do it without typing out /Users/(username)/Documents/Foo/Bar

```
NSString *directoryPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/Foo/Bar", NSHomeDirectory()];    

BOOL isDir;
NSFileManager *fileManager= [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:directoryPath isDirectory:&isDir])
    if(![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:directoryPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL])
        NSLog(@"Error: Create folder failed %@", directoryPath);
```

This doesn't work when I try using NSHomeDirectory() with it. But if I typed out the full path /Users/(username)/Documents/Foo/Ba it works. How can it be done to not have to know the users folder?

EDIT:
directoryPath becomes

```
/Users/(username)/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FAB78255-38D2-49BE-9683-7A0676EA2288/data/Containers/Data/Application/67B0AACE-572A-4808-9535-D221AEEB9EFA/Foo/Bar
```

I just want /Users/(username)

Comment: What do you get for `directoryPath2` when you use `NSHomeDirectory()`?

Comment: And use the `error` parameter to see what the problem is.

Comment: woops I have two paths, edited it to match

Comment: You still need to update your question with the value of `directoryPath`.

Comment: No I don't it's at the top @rmaddy

Comment: You stated that is the value typed in manually. Add `NSLog(@"path = %@", directoryPath);` and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an iOS app. The "Documents" folder of an iOS app's sandbox is not at all related to the user's "Documents" folder on their computer.

Since you appear to be running your iOS in the simulator, the path you are getting is more like what you should be seeing. You do *not* want a path in the user's home directory.

Keep in mind that you can't get access to the "Documents" folder of an iOS app using `NSHomeDirectory()`. That may have worked in older versions of iOS but it fails in iOS 8 and later. The proper code needs to be something like this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsFolder = paths[0];
NSString *directoryPath = [documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Foo/Bar"];
```

Comment: That's still giving me that weird long string

Comment: Right. You are supposed to. Why do you think it's a problem?